# Conditional on first letter

Tags: r, statistics

Suppose my dataset is

| ID | Country | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | A |
| 1 | Austria | A |
| 1 | Austria | A |
| 1 | Belgium | A |
| 2 | Czech | B |
| 2 | Czech | B |
| 2 | Denmark | B |
| 2 | Denmark | C |

I want to create a new variable of each type with the percent each country has within each ID. So

| ID | Country | Type | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Austria | A | 0.75 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Austria | A | 0.75 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Austria | A | 0.75 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Belgium | A | 0.25 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | Czech | B | 0 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 2 | Czech | B | 0 | 0.5 | 0 |
| 2 | Denmark | B | 0 | 0.25 | 0 |
| 2 | Denmark | C | 0 | 0 | 0.25 |

For example, we have four countries that belong to ID 1. It has three Austria's with type A (therefore 0.75) and one Belgium with type A (0.25) therefore falling in to type A.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I noticed you had not accepted a single answer to your previous questions. If you find the answers helpful, you can click on the little tick mark on the left-hand side of the answer to accept it (you can only accept one solution per question) and/or upvote it.

Comment: My sincere apologies! I did not notice it was a thing!

Comment: No need to apologize, just a warm reminder for new joiners in SO :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to `group_by` different variables when deriving the correct percentages.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  group_by_all() |> 
  mutate(value = n()) |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  mutate(value = value/n(),
         rn = row_number(),
         name = Type) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_fill = 0) |> 
  select(-rn) |> 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 × 6
     ID Country Type      A     B     C
  <int> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 Austria A      0.75  0     0   
2     1 Austria A      0.75  0     0   
3     1 Austria A      0.75  0     0   
4     1 Belgium A      0.25  0     0   
5     2 Czech   B      0     0.5   0   
6     2 Czech   B      0     0.5   0   
7     2 Denmark B      0     0.25  0   
8     2 Denmark C      0     0     0.25
```